# Exibindo a data no campo data

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tentando exibir a data do dia no campo `date`:

```
<input type="date" name="dia" />.
```

Sendo que a data eu peguei via JS:

```
var Hoje = new Date();
var data;
Hoje.getDate();
Hoje.getDay();
Hoje.getMonth();
dia = Hoje.getDate();
mes = Hoje.getMonth()+1;
ano = Hoje.getFullYear();

 data = dia +'/'+ mes +'/'+ ano;
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? Dá algum erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de ter em conta que um input `type="date"` aceita uma *string* no formato `aaaa-mm-dd`. Isso significa que o mês tem de ser `01` e não somente `1`.
Se colocares por exemplo `input.value = '2015-1-25';` não vai funcionar.
Repara também que uso "`-`" em vêz de "`/`".

Existe outra maneira amis recente, para browsers modernos, o `.valueAsDate` que aceita diretamente um objeto `Date`.

### Usando `.value`:

```
var Hoje = new Date();

dia = Hoje.getDate();
mes = Hoje.getMonth() + 1;
ano = Hoje.getFullYear();

var data = [ano, mes, dia].map(function (nr) {
    return (nr + '').length == 1 ? '0' + nr : nr;
});

document.querySelector('input[name="dia"]').value = data.join('-');
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7m8a6yfw/

Nesta linha `return (nr + '').length == 1 ? '0' + nr : nr;` junto um zero no caso de a *string* só ter 1 caractere. A ideia em fazer `(nr + '')` é só para converter o numero em *string* ("cast to string").

### Usando `.valueAsDate`:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="dia"]').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdfuzon5/

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54198/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-exibindo-a-data-no-campo-data)